# Connection timing out on webserver?

Tags: centos, nginx, php, php-fpm

My server is currently timing out when I try to view the site.

I tried restarting nginx.
I tried restarting php-fpm.
I tried restarting mysql.

No dice.

I tried rebooting the box.

Still no dice.

I've not applied any updates recently.

Where should I be looking/what tests should I be running to fix this?

nginx error log is full of:

"upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream"

Static files (.jpeg, .html etc) seem to work fine, so it's a php problem I assume.

**EDIT: fixed, see comment below**

Comment: Connection timeout happens at the TCP layer, thus it is independent from the URI and content type. Only way that could cause a difference is if it is somehow configured to fetch different content from different servers, or if it is simply caching all the static files.

Comment: It was a DoS attack that was hitting the CPU through mysql hard enough that php was failing to run (couldn't do a phpinfo() page) but that nginx was managing to serve static files still.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps MySQL got annoyed because of that DoS and added your web server to its black list as max_connection_errors got exceeded? In MySQL, try `FLUSH HOSTS;` and see if it helps. If not, please provide us more info such as error logs.